# CakePHP add model name to information returned in queries

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I want to include the model name in the returned results of a query using CakePHP's `find()` methods.

For instance, if I do a

```
$person = $this->Person->find("first", array(
    "conditions" => array (
        "Person.id" => $id
    )
));
```

I get back

```
Person{id:1, name:Abraham Lincoln}
```

I want to get back

```
Person{id:1, name:Abraham Lincoln, model: Person}
```

I'm fairly front-end oriented. I know I could loop through results and add these at the controller level, but that seems tedious, especially since most of my queries are far more complex, utilizing `contain()`. I imagine somewhere in CakePHP's core there's a place this kind of functionality could be added, I just don't know where.

Essentially, I'm looking for where CakePHP casts the database query to a php variable, so I can inject my additional model value.

I do know I will never use the column name "`model`" anywhere in my application. I'm also certain I want this information where I'm requesting it to be in every singe query, as little sense as it may make.

Comment: I'm curious _why_ you want that - obviously the top-level array key (in this example) contains the model name already.

Comment: @AD7six I'm basically serving the returned model object to the client as JSON and throwing that into Mustache.js. Some of the Mustache templates have editable pieces - I use this to create inputs on the fly and get the information back to the right place. I couldn't figure out how to grab the model with Mustache in the right  place within the template, so I added it back into the lower-level records for use by Mustache.

Comment: @AD7six Also, your insights have been insanely helpful. How do I contact you directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to every model where you need it:

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    foreach($results as $ikey => $item) {
        foreach($item as $skey => $subitem) {
            if(is_array($subitem))
                $results[$ikey][$skey]['model'] = $skey;
            else $results[$ikey]['model'] = $skey;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Unfortunately I wasn't able to get this work when I stored it in AppModel.

Comment: That actually works pretty well, and I can leave it off a model if I like. Thanks!

Comment: For clean code you can make that a behavior to enable/disable as you require (there's no fundamental reason taht wouldn't work in the app model - except possibly running when you wouldn't expect it). Be wary of assuming the structure of `$results` - if it's a `find('list')` it can be a one dimensional array, also lack of curly-braces makes code harder to read. That said: +1.